# How do I convert a string response size to MB in Python?

Tags: python

I am doing a bit of a scraping project where I am scraping some data file information. The issue is that the response is a string that is sometimes in kB, MB, GB etc. What I need is to convert the response I get to MB and drop the text part eg. `290.5kB` should return `0.29` without `MB` at the end.
The scraped section looks like this:
`Format: MapInfo MIF, (290.5 kB)`
Here is my code snippet:

```
f_file_size = file_format.split('Format: ')[1].split(',')[1].strip(' ()')


output_dict['data_files'].append({'file_size': f_file_size})
```

Which outputs:

```
"data_files" : [{
    "file_size": "290.5 kB"
}]
```

Your assistance will be highly appreciated

Comment: That's definitely not the output, there'd be quotes around `290.5kB` (unless you've got custom printing code you've omitted). Regardless, what have you tried? This isn't something with a built-in tool, you're going to need to write a custom parser, and "Please write my code for me" isn't a great question if you show no effort. If you try and fail, and provide a [MCVE] of your attempt, we'll gladly assist you with fixing it.

Comment: Write a function which parses the returned strings and converts them to a number.  Then you can format that number however you like later.

Comment: Thanks for this. I wrote out the code by hand. What I tried was writing if else statements for each kB, GB and MB but I can't divide by a string. Stripping the code of the text part (MB, kB etc) will make it a bit difficult to know what to divide by @ShadowRanger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `re.sub` here with a callback function:

```py
def repl(m):
    val = float(m.group(1))
    unit = m.group(2)

    if unit == 'kB':
        return str(val / 1000)
    elif unit == 'MB':
        return str(val)
    elif unit == 'GB':
        return str(val * 1000)
    else:
        return str(val)  # assume MB as the default

inp = "Format: MapInfo MIF, (290.5 kB)"
output = re.sub(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(\wB)\b', repl, inp)
print(output)  # Format: MapInfo MIF, (0.2905)
```

The idea here is capture a number, possibly floating point, followed by a byte unit at some scale, and pass the quantity and unit to a callback function.  The callback returns only the amount scaled to MB.

Other units can easily be added to the callback function and also the regex pattern can be adjusted as needed.  One optimization here might be to create a dictionary which maps units to conversion factors, e.g.

```py
units = {}
units["kB"] = 1000
units["MB"] = 1
units["GB"] = 0.001
```

Then we can simply lookup the conversion factor instead of using a large if else construct.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by `float(f_file_size[:-2])` as follow

```py
f_file_size = file_format.split('Format: ')[1].split(',')[1].strip(' ()')


output_dict['data_files'].append({'file_size': float(f_file_size[:-2])})
```

Comment: I'm sure this just strips the "kB" or "MB" part but doesn't have any conversion built into it